# React context inside Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to get context variables inside a React Route. This is my code

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/home/:loc" render={(props)=> {
      <AppContext.Consumer>
        {
          context=><Home context={context} />
        }
      </AppContext.Consumer>

    }} />
</Switch>
```

This is my AppContext.js

```
import React from 'react';

export const AppContext = React.createContext();
```

This is how I am setting the context

```
 <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <div className="App">
          <Header />
          <Content />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </AppContext.Provider>
```

This is the error I am getting

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure that the code above is the cause of no-unused-expressions but it contains a problem indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

is not an error but linter warning. `no-unused-expressions` rule often indicates that the code may not work as intended because of developer's mistake.

The problem with posted code is that `render` arrow function doesn't return anything.

It should be:

```
<Route path="/home/:loc" render={(props)=> (
  <AppContext.Consumer>
    {
      context=><Home context={context} />
    }
  </AppContext.Consumer>

)} />
```

`=> {...}` requires explicit return, while  `=> (...)` is implicit return.